# Python3 - Increment number inside text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below text file, which structure is like this: `word` `count`

```
product 5
order 4
tracking 1
```

This means that the word `product` was found `5` times in the input document.

I have a script called `WordFrequency.py`, that is used to find words and how many times they are in an input file:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

def count_words(file_path):
    with open("/Users/oliverbusk/Sites/Sandbox/storage/app/" + file_path, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:

        matches = re.findall(r'\b[a-zA-Z]{3,}\b', f.read())

        wordcount = Counter(matches)

        for word in wordcount:
            string = word + " " + str(wordcount[word])
            write_to_file(string)

def write_to_file(word):
    with open("/Dictionaries/eng.txt", "a+") as f:
        f.write(word + "\n")
```

So basically, above will read the input file `file_path`, and add the word and the count to `eng.txt`.

However, whenever I run it, the result will just get appended to the `eng.txt` file, like:

```
product 5
order 4
tracking 1
product 5
order 4
tracking 1
```

When instead, I want it to increment the `count`, if the word is already present in the `eng.txt` file.

Comment: Looks like you opened the `eng.txt` file in **append** mode instead of **write** mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to read the content of the file first and then increment the count.

**Ex:**

```
import re
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

def count_words():
    #Read Content#
    with open("/Dictionaries/eng.txt", "r") as f:
        data = defaultdict(int)
        for line in f:
            key, value = line.strip().split()
            data[key] = int(value)

    with open("/Users/oliverbusk/Sites/Sandbox/storage/app/" + file_path, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        matches = re.findall(r'\b[a-zA-Z]{3,}\b', f.read())
        wordcount = Counter(matches)
        for word, count in wordcount.items():
            data[word] += count                 #Increment Count

    #Write To File
    write_to_file(data)

def write_to_file(data):
    with open("/Dictionaries/eng.txt", "w") as f:
        for word, count in data.items():
            string = word + " " + str(count)
            f.write(string + "\n")
```

Comment: This deletes the content of `eng.txt` and only adds the last word from my input file to the `eng.txt`

Comment: Updated snippet.

Comment: Now it works perfectly! Just what I wanted. Thanks a lot @Rakesh!